# Google Cloud Source Repositories Git operations hang sometimes for several minutes

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote, google-cloud-source-repos

We're experiencing hangs on Git operations (pull/push etc.) on all our Google Source Repositories since around November 2020. It usually happens 1-2 times out of 10.

We're experiencing this on different computers (both with Ubuntu and Fedora OS with totally different configuration environments) located in 2 different offices in different countries (which all have unfiltered, good quality, regular internet access and we don't use VPNs, so network issues can be ruled out). Changing IPv6/IPv4 connectivity does not seem to affect this.

The fetch and push URLs for our repositories look like this:

`ssh://email@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/xxx/r/yyy`

(We've replaced the email, project name with xxx and the repo name with yyy)

We've tried the following:

- Setting the http.postBuffer both to 524288000 and 5000 but this does not affect the issue (we know that SSH is used but we gave this a shot).
- Running `gcloud auth login` again to refresh credentials

Here's a git pull log excerpt which hangs for minutes, but eventually finished with a success:

```
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: send packet: type 98
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: Ignored env OSP_KSDK_PATH
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: Ignored env QT_PLATFORM_PLUGIN
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
febr 10 09:51:41 debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack '/p/xxx/r/yyy'
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: send packet: type 98
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
febr 10 09:51:41 debug3: receive packet: type 99
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
febr 10 09:51:41 debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: read failed
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: send eof
febr 10 09:55:08 debug3: send packet: type 96
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
febr 10 09:55:08 debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 4
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: receive packet: type 98
febr 10 10:05:08 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 39
febr 10 10:05:08 CANCELLED The operation was cancelled.
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: written 39 to efd 6
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 112
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 99
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: receive packet: type 97
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(211)
febr 10 10:05:08 [type.googleapis.com/devtools.gerritcodereview.proto.GerritCodeReviewError]: {
febr 10 10:05:08   error_type: CLIENT_TIMED_OUT
febr 10 10:05:08 }
febr 10 10:05:08 [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]: {
febr 10 10:05:08   request_id: "d4c27f7f36644520a0da17841c907b00"
febr 10 10:05:08 }
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: written 211 to efd 6
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: send close
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: send packet: type 97
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: is dead
febr 10 10:05:08 debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
febr 10 10:05:08 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
febr 10 10:05:08   #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)
febr 10 10:05:08
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: send packet: type 1
febr 10 10:05:08 debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
febr 10 10:05:08 debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
febr 10 10:05:08 Transferred: sent 3816, received 2100 bytes, in 807.1 seconds
febr 10 10:05:08 Bytes per second: sent 4.7, received 2.6
febr 10 10:05:08 debug1: Exit status 1
febr 10 10:05:08 Already up to date.
```

Here's an excerpt which hangs for minutes and fails with an auth error (sometimes this happens, sometimes it completes like in the previous log):

```
febr 10 09:39:34 debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = hu_HU.UTF-8
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: send packet: type 98
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: Ignored env OSP_KSDK_PATH
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: Ignored env QT_PLATFORM_PLUGIN
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
febr 10 09:39:34 debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack '/p/xxx/r/yyy'
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: send packet: type 98
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
febr 10 09:39:34 debug3: receive packet: type 99
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
febr 10 09:39:34 debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: receive packet: type 98
febr 10 09:45:07 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 232
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 125
febr 10 09:45:07 UNAUTHENTICATED Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other
 valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
febr 10 09:45:07 [type.googleapis.com/devtools.gerritcodereview.proto.GerritCodeReviewError]: {
febr 10 09:45:07   error_type: CREDENTIAL_LIFETIME_TOO_SHORT
febr 10 09:45:07 }
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: written 357 to efd 6
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 99
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: receive packet: type 97
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(99)
febr 10 09:45:07 [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]: {
febr 10 09:45:07   request_id: "5e3ea7c0a78442ff9a1aca05f8d36c5e"
febr 10 09:45:07 }
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: written 99 to efd 6
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: send close
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: send packet: type 97
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: is dead
febr 10 09:45:07 debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
febr 10 09:45:07 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
febr 10 09:45:07   #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)
febr 10 09:45:07
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: send packet: type 1
febr 10 09:45:07 debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
febr 10 09:45:07 debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
febr 10 09:45:07 Transferred: sent 3768, received 1924 bytes, in 333.8 seconds
febr 10 09:45:07 Bytes per second: sent 11.3, received 5.8
febr 10 09:45:07 debug1: Exit status 16
febr 10 09:45:07 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
febr 10 09:45:07
febr 10 09:45:07 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
febr 10 09:45:07 and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone know what we should try to eliminate this occasional hang?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure of using the latest Cloud SDK tools latest release is 327.0.0 https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes

I can see a change in the Cloud Repositories in [November](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_source_repositories).

Update and test your processes.

Comment: We always upgrade to the latest version and currently running 327.0.0.

Comment: I would suggest opening a [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187169&template=0).

Comment: Include the exact command that you are executing as well as your machine description and the role permissions of the caller `IAM & Admin` > `Roles`

Comment: Already done: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/179800049 Redirected to here :)

Comment: Your Issue Tracker thread has been reopened. Please attach the requested info there.